# shouldComponentUpdate for React Tabs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to stop re-rendering of tabs. I'll try to explain as best as I can, but *please* let me know if you need more info or more code.

Currently, I have an app set up inside the tabs which serve as steps that the user has to make to come to the final result. In the first tab, I have states that the user has to set up to apply discounts. It uses

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.updateProductsBasedOnState();
    };
```

Same as tab two. The issue I have is when you're on tab one and you apply whatever discounts/changes you want and you go to tab two, the tab one will reset once you come back to it. It rerenders.

I've tried using React's Pure Component and also setting up just the `shouldComponentUpdate`.

If I add the following shouldComponentUpdate on the Parent, it doesn't let tabs be changed at all. If I set it on any of the children, changing the state does not work (as in, you can't add any discounts):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return this.state.value != nextState.value;
    }
```

EDIT: [Here's the sandbox link of my tabs!](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sun-6ssjn?fontsize=14)

What else can I try? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Try showing how you render the tabs, my guess on tab switch every tab unmounts, also show the `value`, you using `!=` and not `!==` which may lead to some bugs depending on type

Comment: Making sandbox it the best use case https://codesandbox.io, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Hey, thanks for the reply! Added the codesandbox link to my question! Let me know if I need to add anything else. Thank you!!

Comment: There is no code of `shouldComponentUpdate`, how you decide if a component got "reset", it's not a reproducible example

Comment: You mean I haven't added in shouldComponentUpdate inside the App component? I've added it in now, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot to talk about your example, I'll try making it brief and show a brutal example.

> The purpose is to mount some `Content` once and preserve its state on tabs change.

1. There is no point to use `shouldComponentUpdate` in `App` (parent component) because you want to target the `Content` and not the `App` itself. You should read more about this life-cycle and whats its purpose.
2. You are un-mounting the content on every tab switch, try adding the next code in every content component:

```
const log = id => console.log(`Tab${id} Mounted`);

class AddProducts extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    log(1);
  };
  ...
}
```

You will notice that every time you switch tabs, your components go over the `componentDidMount` cycle, that's why they lose their state.

3. To fix it, you need to render all the components you need in your `App` and by using its state, define which component to show. There are plenty of ways to do so, the brutal force one is using [CSS property `display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Now notice how all components mount **once** and on tab switch, they preserve their state.

4. There are many minor tweaks that you should do in your code like avoiding `constructor` and using babel's class methods and so on.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeTabIndex: 0
  };

  handleTabClick = index => {
    console.log('index clicked:', index);
    this.setState({
      activeTabIndex: index
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { activeTabIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container quote align-self-center">
        <TabsHeader
          handleTabClick={this.handleTabClick}
          data={initialData.map(data => data.label)}
          activeTabIndex={activeTabIndex}
        />
        <AddProducts
          style={{ display: activeTabIndex === 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        />
        <ApplyIncentives
          style={{ display: activeTabIndex === 1 ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        />
        <QuoteSummary
          style={{ display: activeTabIndex === 2 ? 'block' : 'none' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57960356-TabRender]

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer and explanation! You helped me understand half of it just by reading this. And the rest I'm looking up because I know what to look for now! You rock, man!